# JasperReports HTML missing objects

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a jrxml file which is displayed properly when previewed in PDF, but the same file doesn't display correctly when previewed in HTML.

Overlapped objects are not displayed. The alignment and formatting also changes.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot display overlapped item in HTML, in Jasper Server at least. There is a similar problem in excel if you have overlapping columns etc.

The best solution all round is not to have overlapping items.

Comment: This answer is completely correct... but in addition, you could choose to export to XHTML rather than HTML. This uses CSS better, and it allows overlapping objects.